# How to disable the screenshot in Windows Phone 8.1 for ionic app?

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, ionic-framework, winjs

I need to disable the screenshot functionality for my ionic WP-8.1 app, were the project template is created in WinJs
Hence I am not able to get the JS code to disable the functionality. 
I try the below code(C# code) by adding a plugin but its not working

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (this.CanSetScreenCaptureEnabled())
        {
            this.SetScreenCaptureEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me out in disabling the functionality.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to prevent OS functionality via an app. At least not in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The C# snippet you have is for a Silverlight app, not a Windows Runtime app. From a Windows Phone Runtime app set the ApplicationView.[isScreenCaptureEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.isscreencaptureenabled.aspx) property.

Here is the JavaScript syntax to call it from your platformOverrides.js or plugin:

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.getForCurrentView().isScreenCaptureEnabled = false;
```

This is demonstrated for a WinJS app in the [Disable screen capture sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Disable-screen-capture-00efe630/sourcecode?fileId=86656&pathId=1472032281).